# Probability given a past outcome

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that I have a basket that contains 9 red balls, and 1 white ball, and I'm drawing at random. I would expect to draw a red ball with probability 0.9. Now, suppose that 10 people (including me) are drawing and it turns out that 5 people drew red, and 5 people drew white (but I'm not sure which group I'm in). It seems as though I should just ignore the original probability of 0.9 and say that my probability of red is 0.5. But, this is sort of counterintuitive because it seems like we would say that the 5 people who drew white are "luckier" in some sense, which is counterintuitive. What should my probability be?

Comment: Your probability of drawing red is $0.9$.

Comment: That's not correct.

Comment: This is the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy). Short-term, drawing 5 white and 5 red may seem lucky. And it is – long-term, you still get 9/10 of the people drawing red.

Comment: I'm looking for Probability(Red | 9 red balls/1 white ball & 5 people drew red, 5 people drew white)

Comment: No, that's wrong - I *am* one of the 10 people who have drawn

Comment: Seriously, read the link provided by Parcly Taxel... it doesn't matter what someone drew (as it is with replacement).

Comment: "That's wrong", "That's wrong", "That's wrong"... Well, you seem to already now the (wrong) answer, what's your question then???

Comment: I know what the gambler's fallacy is, but this is not the gambler's fallacy. The gambler's fallacy states that past outcomes shouldn't be considered for the probability of independent events. This is not the gambler's fallacy, it is new information about the outcome of *my* event. You are all mistaken. I know that the probability is 0.9 without any new information, but now I *also* know that I'm one of 10 people, half of whom chose white and half of whom chose red. The question is: "how should I update my probability in virtue of this *relevant* information"

Comment: "I know that the probability is $0.9$", yet "You are all mistaken"... right... Well, thank you for making our point.

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  If I say "one of you draws red and the other draws white." then you have a $\frac 12$ of being the red winner.  Nothing to do with the a priori probability.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Lulu - yes. That is my instinct, but my question is whether you throw the prior probability out.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding each other. 

user1447447, as far as I can tell, you are asking what is the probability that you belong to the group of 5 people that drew a red ball, when 10 people have drawn 5 white respectively 5 red balls?

Comment: Furrer - yes that is correct.

Comment: Absolutely you do.  More extreme illustration:  If I deal myself a Royal Flush then the probability that I dealt myself a Royal Flush is $1$.  The fact that this was a deeply improbable event has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: In that case, the probability is one half. Lulu's example is cutting clear. What group you belong to is independent of the probability of the original outcomes given the outcomes - after all, you and your mates are no different!

Comment: Ok that's what I thought - my hesitation is that if you have two events, and one is extremely improbable (for example, royal flush vs pair), and I say to two poker players that "you each have one" - it seems weird to say that I'm equally likely to have the flush, but it makes sense.

Comment: Once you ask about an actual sample, the underlying distribution has no bearing.  The sample doesn't know what sort of distribution it came from.